# Automatic warranty scanner?

Tags: warranty

I'm looking for something that runs on either Windows or Linux that will automatically query devices on my network (specifically the HP and Dell servers), determine their serial number, look that serial up against the manufacturer's site to determine warranty expiration status, and have it generate reports.

I tried out Spiceworks, and while nice, it doesn't quite fit my needs.  Something fully automated would be best due to the amount of machines I need to check warranty expiration on.

Anything free would be preferred, but pay software would work as well, provided it has an evaluation.

Comment: Spiceworks should be fully automatic if configured correctly. Make sure you set up the user accounts for the network scan properly, and set up your alerts and reports to show you what you want.

Answer (score 2):

HP and Dell both offer management frameworks (InsightManager and OpenManage respectively) that theoretically do this. You have to install agents on everything so it can pull the correct BIOS information out of each device, but it can be done. They are still failure prone and don't always manage to pull support information out of the respective web-sites, though it is better than keeping track of it all on spreadsheets and Wiki pages.